# java application is opened twice when i double click on my jar-file

Tags: java, eclipse, executable-jar

I've noticed a strange behaviour with my runnable jar which i created in eclipse. when i try to open my application via command line like this:

```
java -jar c:\project\project.jar
```

everything works perfect, the application is executed - same behaviour when i start the application via eclipse.

But when i start my application by double-click on the jar-file my application is opened twice AND there are two different processes in my taskmanager. Interesting also is that the second application is opened lets say a second later when the first one is shown...

i dont understand this strange behaviour - i tried to open my jar-file on another workstation and i also got two running applications.

the jar-file is generated via eclipse: file->Export->Runnable Jar file. i choosed the radiobutton "Package required libraries into generated JAR".

Has anybody any idea?

Comment: Have you tried to click once? ;)

Comment: Which os you are using?

Comment: It may depend on the specifics of your program: I had the same issue, and this is a long shot in terms of your case, but my program was using a `robot` object to open another window and execute various commands such as `VK_ENTER`. As it turns out, the window context wasn't changing accurately and the `ENTER` keystroke was applied to the still-active JAR file in Windows Explorer, executing it multiple times. Along similar lines, there may be a structural issue with your code which may be obvious when posted here.

Answer (score 4):

**Might be this is the problem , Try clicking it only once .**

[image: Open Files Folder in just one click]

Comment: unfortunately its seems not to be a problem caused by the os - i'm using win 7 professional 32 bit. in my folder options i have checked "double-click to open an item"...